# Create hidden cell under UItableview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am not sure if the title make any sense, but I do not how else to describe it in few words.
I have a simple task I want to do. I have a UItableview in my viewcontroller. I want to create a little nice effect, so when you get to the bottom of tableview and scroll a little further down my logo / some tableviewcell will appear. When you release the finger the tableview will scroll back up to the "real" buttom.

I have searched on google and here but cannot find any solution to this. 
Please ask if it is not described clearly:)

It is an effect that is seen in other apps, but I cannot remember the names unfortuantely. Will try to find example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Footer view for your logo in table view.

Answer (score 0):

As Anil said I also got the idea of using the Footer view, but it doesn't provide solution for scrolling out of the box.

So I think the best thing is to set your logo as the `backgroundView` (but so that it is placed in the bottom of the page) and then to set backgroundColor of your cells to white (or whatever color you want to use). It should work exactly like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Would [*UITableViewHeaderFooterView*](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewheaderfooterview) be what you're looking for?

From Apple docs:

> The UITableViewHeaderFooterView class implements a reusable view that
>   can be placed at the top or bottom of a table section. You use headers
>   and footers to display additional information for that section.

Check out this [blog post](http://samwize.com/2015/11/06/guide-to-customizing-uitableview-section-header-footer/).